# X-FRAME OPTIONS in Facebook Messenger

Tags: django, facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating a facebook chatbot and using Django for the backend. The documentation states this regarding webviews on the web.
[image]

Which is the best way to achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers honor the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header that indicates whether or not a resource is allowed to load within a frame or iframe.

You can add this to your `settings.py`

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.messenger.com/'
```

> Note: This will use same `X-Frame-Options` header value for all responses in your
>   site

If you want to set the `X-Frame-Options` header on a per view basis, Read the **[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/clickjacking/)**